# nosetest - to supress traceback with sys.tracebacklimit = 0 do not come in effect

Tags: python, nose, traceback

I wanted to suppress the traceback output, to simple show status as ok or FAIL, ERROR
and sometime with single line to explain failure.

How do we do it ? seem like tracebacklimit=0 does not work.

```
 import sys
 sys.tracebacklimit = 0
 def test_something():
       assert 1 == 2
```

execution show a traceback

```
# nosetests a.py -v
a.test_something ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: a.test_something
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
      self.test(*self.arg)
File "/root/a.py", line 6, in test_something
      assert 1 == 2
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to do this without [writing](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/writing.html) your own plugin, probably something very similar to [Failure Detail](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/failuredetail.html). If you do end up going implementing a plugin, you can can output your results to stdout and suppress stderr output from nose by redirecting it to null. Alternatively, use existing [xunit](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html) plugin for test summary and ignore nose output all together.